# Book series about teens who gain enhanced senses after adopting a wolf

Tags: story-identification, books, powers

I'm looking for a book series about a group of teens who developed increased senses after adopting a baby wolf that was experimented on. The main character is a girl that becomes friends with a group of boys, one of their names was Ben, I think. Each of them had developed one sense that was greater than the others, they each had either an increased sense of smell, sight, hearing , or general physical ability.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It looks like an interesting series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the *[Virals](https://brendanreichs.com/the-books/the-virals-series/)* series by Brendan and Kathy Reichs, starting with the eponymous novel, *[Virals](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7800188-virals)*.

> Tory Brennan, niece of acclaimed forensic anthropologist Temperance Brennan (of the Bones novels and hit TV show), is the leader of a ragtag band of teenage "sci-philes" who live on a secluded island off the coast of South Carolina. When the group rescues a dog caged for medical testing on a nearby island, they are exposed to an experimental strain of canine parvovirus that changes their lives forever.
>
> As the friends discover their heightened senses and animal-quick reflexes, they must combine their scientific curiosity with their newfound physical gifts to solve a cold-case murder that has suddenly become very hot if they can stay alive long enough to catch the killer's scent.
>
> Fortunately, they are now more than friends. They're a pack. They are *Virals*.

Found with a search for `book series teens laboratory wolf heightened senses -werewolf`